# Расстояние между точками на окружности

Tags: excel, координаты, геометрия

Имеем окружность (радиус не имеет значения, например 1), на которой расположены некие точки, полученные при пересечении этой окружности лучом, исходящим из центра окружности под произвольным углом. Как реализовать алгоритм нахождения  ближайшей из точек А, В, С, Д и тд N (доступных по варианту) к точке X, являющейся известной заранее. Пробовал по формуле нахождения минимальной хорды и минимального угла - получаю неверный результат. Реализовать мне это нужно в Excel.

Comment: а какими формулами вы пользовались?

Comment: минимальный угол должен сработать. Только правильно разберитесь с углами >Пи.

Comment: В том и дело, что не могу найти верную методику.

Comment: Что дано на входе?

Comment: Углы, под которыми лучи пересекают окружность

Comment: приведите всё же формулы и входные данные, на которых они не работают.

Comment: Итак, решение я нашел:
=МИН(ABS(ЕСЛИ($C$2:$C$4-$E$2<180;2*SIN(($C$2:$C$4-$E$2)/2);2*SIN((360-$C$2:$C$4+$E$2)/2))))

Здесь из трех значений С2, С3 и С4, выбирается наименьшее для значения Е2. После написания формулы требуется нажать Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: @Alex: не сработает для `$C$2:$C$4-$E$2` равного, например, 400 градусов (в каком диапазоне ваши значения?).

Comment: У меня круг - от 0 до 360 градусов

Answer (score 2):

> Alex Nikush: Итак, решение я нашел:
> =МИН(ABS(ЕСЛИ($C$2:$C$4-$E$2<180;2SIN(($C$2:$C$4-$E$2)/2);2SIN((360-$C$2:$C$4+$E$2)/2))))

Не трогая математику, формулу *Excel* можно сократить (формула массива):

```
=МИН(ABS(2*SIN((ЕСЛИ($C$2:$C$4-$E$2<180;;360)+$E$2-$C$2:$C$4)/2)))
=МИН(ABS(2*SIN((($C$2:$C$4-$E$2>=180)*360+$E$2-$C$2:$C$4)/2)))
```

---

*К вопросу от* **19 Ноября в 15:42 и в 19:10**.

"Шапка" табл.1 (*Объект/Луч/Субъект/Код*) - *A1:D1*

Данные табл.1 *A2:C6*

"Шапка" табл.2 (*Субъект/Код/Луч*) - *A9:C9*

Данные табл.2 *A10:C15*

В *D2* формула массива:

```
=ИНДЕКС($B$10:$B$15;МАКС(ЕСЛИ(МИН(ЕСЛИ(C2=$A$10:$A$15;ABS(2*SIN((ЕСЛИ(B2-$C$10:$C$15<180;;360)+$C$10:$C$15-B2)/2));2))=ЕСЛИ(C2=$A$10:$A$15;ABS(2*SIN((ЕСЛИ(B2-$C$10:$C$15<180;;360)+$C$10:$C$15-B2)/2));2);СТРОКА($10:$15)-9)))
```

Протянуть формулу по строкам (*D2:D6*)

Формула тяжелая, облегчение возможно, но нужно "щупать" живой файл.

---

Без файла *Excel* воспроизведение решения трудоемкое.

Если возникнут вопросы, пишите

*vikttur@list.ru*

Comment: Пытался распространить формулу на столбец. 
Есть таблицы.

    Объект   Луч   Субъект
    Объект1   15   Субъект1
    Объект1   105   Субъект1
    Объект2   50   Субъект2
    Объект2   225   Субъект2
    Объект3   30   Субъект3

    и
     Субъект   Код   Луч
        Субъект1 11  23
        Субъект1 12  53
        Субъект1 13  301
        Субъект2 21  90
        Субъект2 22  45
        Субъект2 23  1 и тд

Как возвратить для минимального расстояния от субъекта до объекта код субъекта? 
Пробовал формулами массива `ИНДЕКС(...НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(СТРОКА)...)` и ИНДЕКС(...ПОИСКПОЗ(МИН)...) 
Не понятно((

Comment: Не понимаю, как связывается полученное значение с исходными данными.

Comment: И мне непонятно :)
Можете объяснить на примере, что нужно?

Comment: Должно быть так

`Объект     Луч   Субъект  Код   
Объект1   15     Субъект1   12
Объект1   105   Субъект1    13
Объект2   50     Субъект2    21
Объект2   225   Субъект2    21
Объект3   30     Субъект3   33`

Возвращаемый код должен соответствовать условию минимального расстояния между Лучом Объекта и Лучом Субъекта. Объекту1 может соответствовать только Субъект1, но у каждого Объекта и каждого Субъекта может быть несколько значений.

Comment: Ответ на второй вопрос добавил к ответу на первый (от 18 ноября, 20:07).